# Moose creating accessors

Tags: perl, moose

given a list of accessors is the following possible? If it is possible how would i create builder method for each, i assumed lazy_build attribute would be doing that? please help

```
my @accessors= qw/type duration process/; # used 3 as example but the list is about 50

foreach my $accessors (@accessors) {
has $accessors => (
    is         => 'rw',
    isa        => 'Str',
    lazy_build => 1,

);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible.  It is both documented to work and trivial to test.

As [documented](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Moose-2.0604/lib/Moose/Meta/Attribute.pm), `lazy_build` does not create builders; it specifies that an attribute should be lazily initialized and that it should call a builder named `_build_${attr_name}`.  You have to supply your own builder methods called `_build_type` etc.

If your attributes all take the same builder (unlikely, but maybe they do), don't say `lazy_build`.  Instead, say `lazy => 1, builder => '_build_stuff'` and implement `_build_stuff` to work for each case.  But like I said, that's unlikely; the fact that you can easily use it in a loop is in fact one of `lazy_build`'s advantages.